# z-index in nested div

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

I have 3 divs which 2 have position:fixed; but, since they are not on the same DOM level, the z-index doesn't work-

Please see

http://jsfiddle.net/hCFzS/

I am trying to move the red div on top of everything but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The div wasn't closed properly. You forgot an `>`

Result: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCFzS/1/). Now it's on top.

Answer (score 2):

Update the html as

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/YSqBB/) Fixed it for you.
Adding `top:0` and `left:0` will position to left and top of the whole body. Also closed your div properly of the `nav` element.